# Carrying out statistics on -log(p)

Tags: probability, p-value, data-transformation, logarithm

I have an $n \times m$ matrix, where each row $\mathbf{v}_i$, for $i \in \{1, \ldots , n\}$, consists of *some* permutation of the set $\{1, \ldots, m\}$ (and so in particular, each $\mathbf{v}_{i, j} \in \{1, \ldots , m\}$).

Let's say that some subset of the $n$ vectors are of "type $A$", and the remaining vectors are of "type $B$.

For my data analysis (in neuroscience) I'm creating an $n \times n$ adjacency matrix. Every vector above is compared to every other vector using Spearman's correlation. Using MATLAB's `corr` functionality, I obtain the $p$ value for each comparison. The $p$ values tend to be highly skewed, with many very low $p$ values, so I populate the adjacency matrix with $-\log(p)$ values. The distribution of $-\log(p)$ values tends to be roughly normal.

I am curious as to whether the vectors of type $A$ tend to be similar to each other, but different from those in type $B$. So one analysis I've done is take all the $-\log(p)$ values in cells which compare $A$ to $A$, and compared those with the $-\log(p)$ values in cells which compare $A$ to $B$, using a t-test.

My question is whether or not this is an appropriate analysis. My PI has raised concerns about whether it is appropriate to carry out statistics on $p$ values.

---

I'll add more information to make things more clear. In actuality, each vector $\mathbf{v}$ can have missing values, in which there is no rank. So, take two row-vectors $\mathbf{v}_{i_1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{i_2}$. For each computation of `corr`, I retain only those indices $j \in \{1, \ldots , m\}$ of $\mathbf{v}_{i_1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{i_2}$ such that neither $\mathbf{v}_{i_1, j}$ nor $\mathbf{v}_{i_2, j}$ is missing. So, actually, computation of `corr` is carried out on two vectors, each of some length $p$ for $p \leq m $.

Furthermore, I have multiple patients in all. For each patient, the value of $n$ may differ.

This is why I have chosen to report $-\log(p)$ values instead of Spearman's $\rho$ values. The reason is that each computation of $\rho$ is carried out using vectors of variable list lengths. And so I used $-\log(p)$ to make sure the measure of similarity is apples to apples, across comparisons and across patients.

---

Additional edits below.

I am interested in sequences of action potentials in bursts of neuronal firing during seizures. Here is a paper that likewise studies sequences of action potentials, in this case during learning and memory.
[pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32139543](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32139543)
In my case, each vector v is a list of ranks of each neuron, where the rank indicates its spiking order in a burst of activity. A is the seizure state, and B is at rest.

My hypothesis is that vectors in the seizure state are similar to each other, vectors in the non seizure state are similar to each other, but vectors in the seizure state are not similar to those in the non seizure state. Therefore I ran a one-way ANOVA (not t test) on the A to A -log(p) values, the A to B -log(p) values, and the B to B -log(p) values.

To be clear, though, I'm not that interested in proving statistical significance. Usually the difference between these groups is very strong and can be seen visually. What I'm much more interested in is how to report the values themselves. To me the two main options are 1) -log(p) and 2) simply reporting rho. I moved away from rho because of the issue discussed above, where vector length can be different across comparisons and across patients. However if this is the best option I'm open to returning to it.

---

After talking with my PI and various people in my lab, I will probably simply report Spearman's $\rho$ values directly, instead of $-log(p)$.

Comment: "Appropriate" for what end and based on what assumptions?  Regardless, it strikes me as *superfluous,* because the processes of going from Spearman correlation to $p$ to $-\log(p)$ is just a sequence of monotonic re-expressions.  So: simply compute the matrix of Spearman correlations and analyze at in a way that is suitable for whatever your underlying model and objectives might be.  (Applying t-tests in this context looks like an abuse of t-tests, but it's hard to say from such little information.)

Comment: I provided a bit of a simplistic toy example above to try to illustrate the premise, but I realize now that it may have omitted a few key features.

Comment: And so I have now added more information to the main question above. Given this, $-log(p)$ no longer varies monotonically with $\rho$.

Comment: $-\log(p)$ always varies monotonically with $p$.  This is a statement about math, not about your data.

Comment: In the above, I meant $-log(p)$ doesn't vary monotonically with RHO (Spearman's $\rho$). Of course $-log(p)$ varies monotonically with $p$. 

My rationale for using $-log(p)$ rather than simply $p$ was to use the log transform to make the data closer to normal rather than highly skewed.

Comment: I appreciate that the variable length of the vectors makes $p$ no longer a monotonic function of the statistic, but this is such a strange and theoretically unsupported use of p-values that it's worth exploring why you are proposing such a procedure.  That is why I have asked what your objectives and underlying model might be.

Comment: @whuber, i agree with you that it's unusual as written. i had the following idea: instead of taking $-\log(p)$, take $\text{GaussianCDF}^{-1}(p)$. this gives something which is Gaussian under the null hypothesis, and perhaps makes more sense to run t-tests on. thoughts?

Comment: I haven't read anything in this thread that indicates what you're trying to test or why; but generally, proposing many t-tests on interdependent data doesn't work.

Comment: I am interested in sequences of action potentials in bursts of neuronal firing during seizures. Here is a paper that likewise studies sequences of action potentials, in this case during learning and memory. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32139543/ In my case, each vector v is a list of ranks of each neuron, where the rank indicates its spiking order in a burst of activity.  A is the seizure state, and B is at rest.

Comment: My hypothesis is that vectors in the seizure state are similar to each other, vectors in the non seizure state are similar to each other, but vectors in the seizure state are not similar to those in the non seizure state. Therefore I ran a one-way ANOVA (not t test) on the A to A -log(p) values, the A to B -log(p) values, and the B to B -log(p) values.

Comment: To be clear, though, I'm not that interested in proving statistical significance. Usually the difference between these groups is very strong and can be seen visually. What I'm much more interested in is how to report the values themselves. To me the two main options are 1) -log(p) and 2) simply reporting rho. I moved away from rho because of the issue discussed above, where vector length can be different across comparisons and across patients. However if this is the best option I'm open to returning to it.

Comment: @whuber and others, let me know if this helps clarify things.

Comment: It would be great if you could include that extra information from your last comments in your question, since they help to understand it. Also, comments get deleted after a while, and information is easier to find in the question.

Comment: You loose information about the direction of correlation (positive or negative) when you look at p-values instead of the original correlation coefficients. As to taking log of p-values: admittedly, I sometimes use $-\log(p)$ myself as a kind of "magnifying glass" for small p-values when analysing simulation results (not in publications, though). Using these p-values for further analysis: as @whuber warned, they have complex dependencies. Tests like ANOVA assume independence. Results from such tests will be invalid.

Comment: Why would you not directly work with the (Spearman) correlations? For example, if two variables have correlation 0.45, p=0.01 and two others have cor. 0.2, p=0.001, still the correlation tells you that the first pair is estimated to be stronger connected than the second, despite the higher p.

Comment: t-tests by the way won't work for any of these suggestions as correlations and also p-values involving the same variable won't be independent (which often is a much bigger problem than issues with normality). Same issue with ANOVA.

Comment: "I moved away from rho because of the issue discussed above, where vector length can be different across comparisons and across patients." In my view that's more a problem with p-values than with correlations, as the latter measure strength of correlation whereas the former compromise that with indication against the null, which relies on the sample size.